# Can't serialize an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, serialization, collections, arraylist

This is a followup to [Serializing a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365940/)

I'm trying to implement loading and saving for a game I'm working on.

I want to save a `Maze` which contains, among other attributes, an `ArrayList` of `Entity`.

Entity is a super class for Dragon, Hero and Item. All three of these types can be contained at once in the vector.

Using the "automatic" serialization mechanism (adding `implements Serializable` to `Maze`) saves all attributes but the `ArrayList`.

Why does this happen?

My code is below, for completeness' sake.

```
package logic;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public final class LoadAndSave {
    public static final transient boolean available = false;

    public static final boolean serialize(Object obj) {

        // Write to disk with FileOutputStream
        FileOutputStream saveFile;
        try {
            saveFile = new FileOutputStream("game.sav");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }

        // Write object with ObjectOutputStream
        ObjectOutputStream objOut;
        try {
            objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
            return false;
        }

        // Write object out to disk
        try {
            objOut.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static final Object load() {
        FileInputStream fileIn;
        try {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream("game.sav");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            return null;
        }

        // Read object using ObjectInputStream
        ObjectInputStream objIn;
        try {
            objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        // Read an object
        Object obj;
        try {
            obj = objIn.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return obj;
    }

}
```

Comment: Stupid question, but have you also added `implements Serializable` to `Entity`?  For the list to serialize, all of the objects in the list (and all of the non-primitive fields in all of the objects) must implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `Entity` serializable too? (you mentioned that just Maze is serializable).

And be sure that the list is not defined as **transient** or **static**, otherwise it will be skipped by the serialization mechanism.

Comment: Ii is hardcoded in the Class definition, so it is already serialized by definition. Of course the Class definition version must be the same for both the serializer and deserializer

Comment: The problem is that the List instance is mutable. What you say is true only for immutable constants.

Comment: Even though this thread is old, this provided the perfect answer for me. "Static objects are skipped by serialization mechanism"

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you close your streams. Your code for load() can be simplified to look something like this:

```
ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
try {
    objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("game.sav"));
    return objIn.readObject();
} catch (Exception exception) {
    // Deal with errors
    return null;
} finally {
    if (objIn != null) {
        try {
            objIn.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {}
    }
}
```

serialise() can be altered in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

I checked Your code with the following assumptions:

```
class Entity implements Serializable {}
```

and:

```
private char[][] mazeWalls = new char[0][0];

private Vector<Entity> entities = new Vector<Entity>();
```

...and it works perfectly, serializing and deserializing empty `Entity` objects...